# .kv file is not supported

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, kivy-language

My `.kv` file is not supported by VScode. VScode suggested two extensions to work with `.kv` files which are `Kivy` and `KVlang`. I installed them both but I still get an error: `Kivy files require #:kivy !ex`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `#:kivy 1.x` at the top of your .kv file. Replace the 1.x with whatver version you are using for example I am using 2.0 so mine looks like `#:kivy 2.0`

Comment: Thank you so much!